# Redirect given a certain url

Tags: url-routing, url-shortener

I'm writing a url shortener, I already solve url shortening. Given a certain long URL (LURL), I get a CODE with the help of a script and a database to form a short URL (SURL) of the type:

```
mysite.com/CODE
```

So the ralationship between the code and the LURL is stored and must be consulted in the DB. Now as you can see I need a way to do that. My plan is that all the all url in mysite.com direct to the same page where the CODE is taken as a parameter and in this way make a consult in the db fetching the code from the SURL and then redirect with a script to the LURL.

I dont want to generate a SURL that uses a GET request like:

```
mysite.com/?CODE
```

It would be easier but I decided not to do it because it defeats the propose of url shorteners by occupying a character unnecessarily.

How would you implement it? Is this method convenient? If you do not think so I would really appreciate you give me your opinion. Maybe there are better ways to do it now that I already have the DB and the shortening algorithm. See you later.

Comment: Are you asking how to run your code for all requests? What language / server?

Comment: What technology stack? What web server?

Comment: You can still use the url of the form: mysite.com/CODE. In your code, you can first get the full URL, the use explode or split method (with / as the delimeter) to separate the urls to array which contains ["mysite","CODE"], array[1] value is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Shadow_boi What are you suggesting to use? The thing is that I don't know how to do it. I thought the only posibility of grabbing part of the url was with GET requestes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php
check out the curPageURL() function.

```
$pageURL = curPageURL();
$itemArray= explode("/", $pageURL);
$myCode = $itemArray[1];
```

something like that will do, but not tested. It just gives you an idea of what you can do.

also, to get the url, here is an simplified version: http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/27.html